# Why does this complex rational give an overflow error in Julia?

Tags: math, julia

When I want Julia (0.4.3) to compute `(2.4 - 1.2im) // (0.7 - 0.6im)`, it gives an overflow error:

```
ERROR: OverflowError()
 in * at rational.jl:188
 in // at rational.jl:45
 in // at rational.jl:42
```

However `(24 - 12 im) // (0.7 - 0.6im)`, mathmatically essentialy the same, does work. Also, `(2.4 - 1.2im) / (0.7 - 0.6im)` works too but this doesn't give a rational of course.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Are there rationals that Julia can't work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
(24//10 - 12im//10) / (7//10 - 6im//10)
```

instead.

Why does this happen? The numbers you write are floating point numbers—they are not 0.7 or 2.4, but rather approximations of those numbers. You can see this effect by converting to a Rational:

```
julia> Rational{Int64}(0.7)
3152519739159347//4503599627370496
```

The `//` operator used in your question did an implicit conversion to rationals, so results like these are observed.

Now why did an `OverflowError` occur? Because the type is `Rational{Int64}`, which means both numerator and denominator can only store numbers within the range of an `Int64`. Note what happens when we try to square this number, for instance:

```
julia> Rational{Int64}(0.7) * Rational{Int64}(0.7)
ERROR: OverflowError()
 in *(::Rational{Int64}, ::Rational{Int64}) at ./rational.jl:196
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46
```

The `OverflowError` tells us that the resulting rational is no longer exactly representable in this type, which is a good thing—after all, the whole point of `Rational` is to be exact! This could be fixed with `Rational{BigInt}`, but of course that comes with a substantial performance penalty.

So the root of the issue is that `0.7` and the like are floating point literals, and are therefore not exactly `0.7`. Indeed, expressed exactly, `0.7` is `0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`. Instead, using `7//10` avoids the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Now I know you can't use floats in rationals (because floats aren't exact).

Comment: I reported this as a Julia bug a while ago and Simon Byrne has a fix, which consists of disallowing this use of //. On a phone so can't put the references here right now.